# Last cell in a column dataframe from excel using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I just had a quick question. How would one go about getting the last cell value of an excel spreadsheet when working with it as a dataframe using pandas, for every single different column. I'm having quite some difficulty with this, I know the index can be found with len(), but I can't quite wrap my finger around it. Thank you any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can index the last cell using [-1]

Comment: I get an error that says that says                                                       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'

Comment: You need to provide more detail.[ask]

Comment: Is this what you want `df.tail(1)` ?

Answer (score 4):

If you want the last cell of a dataframe meaning the most bottom right cell, then you can use `.iloc`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,101).reshape((10,-1)))
df
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8    9
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
1  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19   20
2  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29   30
3  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39   40
4  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49   50
5  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59   60
6  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69   70
7  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79   80
8  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89   90
9  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  100
```

Use `.iloc` with -1 index selection on both rows and columns.

```
df.iloc[-1,-1]
```

Output:

```
100
```

Answer (score 2):

[`DataFrame.head(n)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) gets the top n results from the dataframe.  [`DataFrame.tail(n)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html) gets the bottom n results from the dataframe.

If your dataframe is named `df`, you could use `df.tail(1)` to get the last row of the dataframe.  The returned value is also a dataframe.